How to remove repeated page numbers from TOC in MS Word?
I want my table of contents not to repeat page numbers. I tried to manually edit the text as if it was a normal text box but that just doesn't work. TOCs are a pain when it comes to manually editing them. I then successfully edited it by editing the field codes manually for EVERY repeated number, but that is a long process and everytime i update the table, my "long" work goes down the drain and i have to do it all over again!
So is there some way to do it automatically? Ideally, i'd like to have a "do not repeat page numbers" button in the TOC options, but i see that's apparently too much to ask for...
Attached are two pictures to show what i did by manually editing the code fields for every line:
Before:

After:


You could likely devise a macro to do what you want; absent that, though, the closest you're going to get (which, depending on your heading structure, may be very close) is for page numbers to appear for only one heading level (e.g., the highest). That's easy to do. There's no button for what you're trying to do because it doesn't make much sense from a reader standpoint. As a rule, readers don't go to a TOC because they want to know what's on page x of the doc. Instead, they want to know, e.g., what info the doc contains, how it's organized and arranged, and where the info about x is.

@cnread I already know how to only display page numbers for certain heading levels, but that wouldn't suit my case, because the pages don't all start with the same heading level...
"what info the doc contains, how it's organized and arranged, and where the info about x is." that is exactly what i'm trying to do, but in a more elegant way by removing repeated numbers. By having a bunch of repeated numbers it's easy to mix them up, while by having only non-repeating page numbers, the reader already knows that anything under that is at that page, without weighing too much on the eye. [see edit]

Agree with @cnread that a macro is the way to go. I can just about imagine doing it using field codes if you were already generating your TOC from TC fields, but AFAICS you aren't.

Have you applied an appropriate heading style to your writing?
Word can recognize subtitle and sub-subhead text so that with it you can create an automatic table of contents in Word.
If you have made changes to the document that affect the subtitles or page numbers of the subtitles and/or sub-subheads, you can update the contents of the Table of Contents by clicking Update Table.

Yes all the headings are appropriately assigned, in fact the TOC indenting is perfect, as it should be.
Though i'm guessing my problem was misunderstood here because what's in your answer isn't really relevant to my problem...
I'll try to re-explain it: my TOC is 99% perfect and it gets created automatically with no issue. What i would like to do is to remove the repeating numbers you can see in the "before" picture, so that it will result as in the "after" picture. The issue is that i have to do it manually, which is a very very long process (i have to edit every single field code)...
